# Bitwise & operation in Apex

Tags: apex

I am unable to do the below operation in apex class. the sencond line of the code where I'm doing bit-wise AND is throwing error - expecting a right parentheses, found 'xff'. Please advice any workaround.

```
Long codeBinary = Base32Decode(myCode);
 Integer myCode2 = (Integer)(codeBinary & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Possible that the & operator does not support Integers and Long as per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apex Code does not support hexadecimal, octal, or binary number bases in source code. Unlike Java, it only supports decimal base (base-10), so you have to write the code as follows:

```
Long codeBinary = Base32Decode(myCode);
Integer myCode2 = (Integer)(codeBinary & 255);
```

Comment: +1, thx for checking the documentation link And providing the actual answer!

Comment: @glls Yeah, it's literally just one extra word, "not," that is kind of a significant mistake.